# Testing endogeneity against decision probability

Tags: regression, probability, stata, treatment-effect, hausman

I am working with a model where the literature suggests there is potential endogeneity between the dependent variable and the primary independent variable of interest (a binary treatment).  However, there is a logical argument that selection may be made into the treatment across the spectrum of the continuous dependent variable.  I have a dataset (N=513) where I am trying to determine if selection to treatment is essentially random with respect to the dependent variable.

Is there a way to test the probability of selection to treatment to demonstrate that there is no endogeneity?  I have already done the regular tests for endogeneity and the results have been inconclusive.  I want a "positive" result that will support the lack of endogeneity, or that will demonstrate endogeneity does in fact exist.

Comment: If the outcome is independent of the treatment, then your treatment effect is zero. Are you sure you are testing what you explained above? Give the specific example you work on, so that we could understand the context and the logic. (Yeah, that's your dissertation work or something, and people are going to steal your ideas. Right.) Ask this on statalist, and see if Austin Nichols has anything to say.

Comment: I think something is not right with terminology. You are building model $y=f(x)+u$ where $y$ is the dependent variable, $x$ is the independent variable (selection to treatment), and $u$ is the error term. Endogeneity means that $x$ and $u$ are correlated. Now you want to determine that $x$ is essentialy random with respect to $y$, which essentialy translates to independence of $x$ from $y$. But then your model will make no sense.

Comment: @cadamt, I wrote my comment independently of StasK, i.e. I saw his comment after I posted mine. As you see we ask similar question, but word it differently.

Comment: My understanding is that selection bias is a form of endogeneity.  The example is as follows: The dependent variable is a continuous asset index.  The ID of interest is household remittances (money sent to households by migrating members).  The literature says that asset levels can affect migration decisions which can affect remittance levels.  My data is showing that the endogeneity question is inconclusive.  I am using treatreg because the ID is a binary variable indicating whether remittances were received or not by the household.  I did not explain it well before, thanks.